# Python - How can a process be killed (not subprocess)

Tags: python, ubuntu, process, multiprocessing

Say I have code something like:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def pro_a():       
    #execute some code that runs a radio program

def pro_b():
    #execute some code that keeps a GUI running

.
.
. #some code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Process(target=pro_a).start()
    Process(target=pro_b).start()
```

How can I end these processes after they have started? I've tried .end(), .quit(), .terminate() and each time, the command window says 'Process' object has no attribute '...' (Linux)

In my specific code, I'm running GNU radio at a certain center frequency, then I want my GUI to be able to have a button that when pushed, updates the center frequency, then closes the processes and re-runs them so that the new center frequency is used.

Comment: `.terminate()` should work, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate. Show your code that tries to terminate the process.

Comment: I was trying to terminate in a function outside of main, and it didn't like it for some reason. When I tried to terminate in main, it worked. I'm trying to get my callBack function to terminate another process. If I could get my function to return something to main it would work I think, but i'm having trouble with that too.

Comment: Maybe the problem was variable scope, because the variable wasn't in scope outside `main`.

Comment: I think I figured it out somewhat. I need to start the process in the function to be able to terminate it in the function. Otherwise it gives me an error. The problem is I need to start it in main, and end it if the button is pushed so I need to find a workaround now.

Comment: Assign the process to a global variable that you can access in the function that runs when the button is pushed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Comment**: I need to terminate it ... from another process

You can do it using `os.kill(...`.

> **os.kill(pid, sig)**
>   Send signal sig to the process pid. Constants for the specific signals available on the host platform are defined in the signal module.

For instance:

```
os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

> **Note**: Watch out the warnings about `kill` a `process` in the Documentation.
>   Python » 3.6.1 Documentation [multiprocessing.Process.terminate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate)

---

If you use it this way, you get the return value from  `.start()` an  that's `None`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p =Process(target=pro_a).start()
```

You have to do it for instance:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p= Process(target=pro_a)
    p.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    p.terminate()
```

Comment: This terminates the process after 5 seconds, I need to terminate it after a button from another process is pushed.

Comment: @DamianConnors It's just an example, you can use whatever criteria you want.